# What section of the US Embassy issues Visas and how do I address them in a formal letter?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, embassies

I need to travel to the US. I have heard that we need to prove somehow that we have a strong affinity to a country outside the US which we will return to after our visit. For this I plan to also show a recommendation letter from my employer (among other things) which states that I am very important member of his team and I am very busy with my project, basically implying that he trusts me enough to go to this trip and then return to my work. I am not sure who I should address this letter to.

As a rough draft, I prepared this:

```
To,
The Visa Issuance Department,
US Embassy
```

But I'm sure that's not correct
Who should such a letter be addressed to?

```
To,
The Incharge/Chairperson,    
Visa Consular Section,  
US Embassy
```

perhaps?

What else should I keep in mind during the interview?

I have all the obvious documents such as my academic record, police reports, passport, personal invitation letter from the US, etc. Are there anything else that need to prepare?  Besides the DS-160 confirmation page, valid passport and photo, the website just says bring any supporting documents to make my case stronger. Is there any document  that I might have left out? Is it necessary to make and present a CV with academic and work history?

Comment: They are normally vice consuls, but the salutation (if you're going to use one) would be "To the Consular Officer". Even if you know the person's name.

Comment: I recently had to do this, and the letter was addressed simply "The Embassy of the United States of America, Consular Section"; followed by "To Whom It May Concern".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The department is: Consular Section. The generic title: Consular Officer

But ultimately addressing it to the United States Embassy is just as effective.  A perfect salutation will not effect your visa application's chances.  What counts is the content and that content should show why you will return ... a good salary, a team leader, a long time as an employee, job waiting your return, etc.

Other good proof of return would be: if you are any sort of a care provider, perhaps you have children to come back to care for, perhaps you have parents who live with you and you take care of; do you own a house (renting doesn't mean much anymore, unless you have a very long term lease on an upscale place); are you a partner in a business; have a nice new car that you are making payments on.  They want to see things that force you to return home for.

Big bank accounts are no longer of much value for the "prove you are coming home" aspect, as with internet banking you can access your funds anywhere.  But they still like to see some money as proof of being able to support yourself while traveling in the USA.